# Why do we need void type in Promotion Traits class from C++ template complete guide book?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, traits

I'm reading templates complete guide book and have a question:

Assume we have template IfThenElse that takes a boolean nontype template parameter to select one of two types parameters:

```
template<bool C, typename Ta, typename Tb> class IfThenElse;

template<typename Ta, typename Tb>
class IfThenElse<true, Ta, Tb>
{
public:
    typedef Ta ResultT;
};

template<typename Ta, typename Tb>
class IfThenElse<false, Ta, Tb>
{
public:
    typedef Tb ResultT;
};
```

And the promotion class:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Promotion;

template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Promotion
{
public:
    typedef typename IfThenElse<(sizeof(T1) > sizeof(T2)),
                                T1,
                                typename IfThenElse<(sizeof(T1) < sizeof(T2)),
                                                    T2,
                                                    void>::ResultT>::ResultT ResultT;
};
```

So, if sizeof(T1) > sizeof(T2), ResultT gives us T1 and if sizeof(T1) < sizeof(T2), we have T2. But, otherwise, it gives void as ResultT.

Can somebody explain, why?
And why we can't just write something like

```
typedef typename IfThenElse<(sizeof(T1) > sizeof(T2)),
                            T1,
                            T2>::ResultT ResultT;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the Promotion class?

Comment: In this example, if `sizeof(T1) == sizeof(T2)`, then `ResultT` will be `void`.  Your proposed replacement would make it `T2`.

Comment: "Promote to the type whose size is larger" is fundamentally a heuristic. When the size of `T1` is the same as the size of `T2`, it doesn't know what the final type should be, so it uses `void` to basically make it a compile error. This way the end user is forced to write a specialization for that case that has the correct behavior, rather than silently using a possibly incorrect type. This whole trait is pretty much obsolete in C++11 due to `decltype`.

Comment: Thank you, guys, every answer and, especially, the last one, were very useful. Thanks.